# AWS Athena Returning 400 Error on getQueryExecution

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to check the status of an executing Athena query using the NodeJS AWS SDK using AWS.Athena.athenaConn.getQueryExecution and am receiving the following error;

```
{
    "message": "Query has not yet finished. Current state: QUEUED",
    "code": "InvalidRequestException",
    "time": "2023-01-27T16:51:23.355Z",
    "requestId": "c64ee58c-e326-4223-8d80-8323a25e8fe0",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 89.10527399170958
}
```

It seems the function can find the query and note it as QUEUED, but I don't understand why it is returning as a 400 status code. Below is the code I am using.

```
import sleep from "../sleep.js"
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'


export default async (credentials) => {

    const athenaConn = new AWS.Athena({
            accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    })

    const startQueryExecutionResponse = await athena.startQueryExecution(params = { QueryString: "select * from database.table" }).promise()

    let status = "UNKNOWN"
    do {
        await sleep(1000)
        status = await getQueryStatus(athenaConn, startQueryExecutionResponse)
    } while (status === "QUEUED" || status === "RUNNING")

    return await athena.getQueryResults(startQueryExecutionResponse).promise()
}

const getQueryStatus = async (athenaConn, startQueryExecutionResponse) => {
    const result = await athenaConn.getQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionResponse).promise()
    return result.QueryExecution.Status.State || "Unknown"
}
```

I am trying to access the status of the query in order to wait for the execution to finish, and would expect a non error response from which I can pull the status, and check repeatedly until it has completed.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information, thanks.

Documentation for reference;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html#getQueryExecution-property